# CSS popup jumps back to top of page when closed

Tags: html, css, popup

Can anyone tell me a solution to make the page not jump back to the top when this CSS driven popup box closes?

At the moment the popup opens in the correct place but when you close it, the page jumps back to the top.

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color:#721213;
  background-size: cover;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: orange;
  margin: 100px 0;
}

.box {
  width: 20%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
  padding: 35px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 20px/50px;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid orange;
  border-radius: 20px/50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
.button:hover {
  background: orange;
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
.overlay:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.popup {
  margin: 70px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 40%;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
  min-height:500px;
}

.popup h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  color: #333;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.popup .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  transition: all 200ms;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}
.popup .close:hover {
  color: orange;
}
.popup .content {
  max-height: 30%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.iframe {
 width:95%;
 display:block;
 margin:0px auto 0px auto;
 height:500px;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:50%; margin:20px auto; background-color:#000; height:1000px;"></div>

<div style="width:50%; margin:20px auto; height:500; padding:200px 50px 20px 50px;">

<a href="#popup1">Let me Pop up</a>

<div id="popup1" class="overlay">
 <div class="popup">
  <h2>Here i am</h2>
  <a class="close" href="#">×</a>
  <div class="content">
            <iframe class="iframe" src="http://www.impressdesign.com.au/clients/IMP/test.pdf"></iframe>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: First of all, it's worth mentioning, that reason of returning to top of the page is usage of `#` anchor (in closing link), which, by default, leads to top/begining of the page...

Comment: Well without JavaScript it would be hard to do since you are using hashes.

Answer (score 3):

**Weave:** http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#3cfa8a8181c0ffdc30103eb2bc19d9b3

**Weave:** *(properly use a hash on an href)*
http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#3a84a44278b04eea7b5d0f067ba22427

**Stop using** `href="#"` and *start using* `href="javascript:void(0)"` instead.

The reason it jumps to the top is because when you use a hash in a href attribute it directs to an ID if none is specified it goes to the top by default. Unless you use `e.preventDefault()` using a [click event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click) in JS.

Because you're using `:target` This can easily be fixed by targeting a new ID.

So change this...

```
<a href="#popup1">Let me Pop up</a>
<a class="close">×</a>
```

to this...

```
<a href="#popup1" id="showpopup">Let me Pop up</a>
<a class="close" href="#showpopup">×</a>
```

and it's fixed!

**NOTE:** [You can do the same effect](http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#7d6f484fdf796682fc5a1a2cc315ff06) using a `input[type=checkbox]` instead of `:target`: http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#8d7733f82faf240e0edcb6739c5d1a1a

A few key notes:

```
margin:0px auto 0px auto;
```

> Values of 0 shouldn't have units specified.

Also it's bad practice to add CSS to your HTML element

```
<div style="width:50%; margin:20px auto; background-color:#000; height:1000px;"></div>

<!-- 
  Instead put your CSS in your style sheet as a class;
  that way it's easier to manage, maintain and get help if needed.
-->
<div class="box"></div>
```

Here is an example of one way on how to properly use a hash tag on a href attribute.

```css
body {
  padding: 1em;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.left {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<ul class="left">
  <li>
    <a href="#lorem">Lorem.</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#ipsum">Ispum!</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#dolor">Dolor!</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#sit">Sit!</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#amet">Amet!</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<p id="lorem" class="left">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste distinctio omnis a nihil, quisquam nisi similique facere, reprehenderit sint nostrum. Ipsa quibusdam, adipisci laudantium nam voluptatum quasi animi placeat eveniet.
</p>

<p id="ipsum" class="left">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel tempora quasi, maiores debitis cupiditate laboriosam alias placeat temporibus veritatis. Quisquam, debitis dolorem saepe enim maiores, ex numquam corporis atque magnam.
</p>

<p id="dolor" class="left">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione architecto quia officiis, amet. Eaque, et quia ducimus possimus rem suscipit, maxime, porro mollitia, corporis sequi magnam debitis. Expedita iure, maiores.
</p>

<p id="sit" class="left">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt ipsum vitae quasi, id reiciendis iure qui veritatis voluptatibus omnis libero ea, labore voluptate maxime, ducimus tenetur, deleniti. Rem, consequatur, accusantium.
</p>

<p id="amet" class="left">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum maiores saepe sunt commodi soluta minus ad. Facilis magnam, distinctio voluptatibus ratione iste, laboriosam hic perspiciatis molestiae repellat accusamus tempora cumque!
</p>

<a href="#">Go to top</a>
```

Comment: the popup does not seem to close by replacing the href, or am I doing something wrong? https://jsfiddle.net/go0tbr6x/3/

Comment: You asked why does it jump to the top and I explained why. Its not working because of :target. Ask I stated in my answer I suggest using a checkbox instead of :target for this method. As it will not jump to the top.

Comment: Firstly - Thanks for the feedback. I also know about putting CSS into the HTML. That was just done to mock up this example quickly.

I also didn't post the previous comment... But they are right. If I change the '#' to the js sniper then the popup doesnt close.

Comment: That's because you're using :target. The only way to solve that is direct the close hash to the anchor that opens the dialog. (which is why i prefer using a checkbox)

Comment: Ok thanks. I looked at your checkbox option but I couldn't figure out the HTML side of it...

Comment: I revised my answer and here's a WIP I made so you can understand the checkbox more (untested) - http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#7d6f484fdf796682fc5a1a2cc315ff06

Answer (score -2):

it happens because your button for closing is a element and href="#" change it to div element instead of a
EDIT : 
i dont know why i got arrow down/point down but
i will explain it easier for you
Your CODE :

```
<div class="popup">
        <h2>Here i am</h2>
        <a class="close" href="#">×</a>
</div>
```

The what i suggest :

```
<div class="popup" id="popup">
        <h2>Here i am</h2>
        <div onClick="document.getElementById('popup').style.display='none';">X</div>
</div>
```

we added id="popup" to (div.popup) element, then we replaced " element" close button with

Comment: I don't quite understand this... If I make it a div and not an a element then its no longer a button - isn't it? So how do you close the popup...?